# Possible to Use C# to Simulate AngularJS login submission like Post?

Tags: c#, angularjs, http, authentication, ng-submit

I see a web page that has `<form name="formName" ng-submit=...` and I am curious if there is a way to log into the site with C# .Net.

I am familiar with using c# to send "Post" data including HttpClient PostAsync, but it's hard for me to search for this because every article talks about an angularjs controller or about going from an angularjs page to some other page. Even getting pointed in the right direction would be very helpful!

Post Example I found

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("pqpUserName", "admin"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "test@123")
    };
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
var response = client.PostAsync("youruri", content).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
}
```

Comment: I think you need to trace the code a bit more to see what `ng-submit` actually does. Alternatively you can see the `network`activity in the chrome browser to see if the page is doing a `POST` call to the server or not. From there you can find out information to replicate the `REST` call. Only then you can think about doing the same from your `C#` application.

Comment: Thank you for that information. Trace the code a bit to see what ng-submit actually does... By this you mean keep the chrome developer tools open? I think I understand what you are saying... I have 0 experience with Angular or tracing rest calls though and for the life of me couldn't find an article that talks about doing this. I will try playing with it more and see if I can see any more information... Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

First of, wrap classes which implement IDisposible interface with the [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement. It's a great feature and makes sure the resource dispose method get's called when your code is done.

To make this work, without knowing the actual authentication type but I guess you run with bearer tokens here, you need to pass the grant_type in the url as well.

Try it like this

```
var postData ="grant_type=password&pqpUserName=admin&password=test@123";

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData))
    {
        content.Headers.Clear();
        content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("youruri", content);
        var apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TResult>();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. I was aware of the using statements but I am lazy and kind of treading on new water, however I actually think it's great that you pointed that out :) Thank you
2. Is there a way to tell which authentication type a website is using from the view source? i see tried your suggestion but I received the login page as a result (assuming my post failed)
<form name="loginForm" ng-submit="submit(loginForm)" novalidate>
<input type="email" id="email2" class="form-control" name="email2" placeholder="Email address" ng-model="email2" ng-class="{'error': submitted && loginForm.email2.$invalid}"

Comment: probably not helpful but here are some other tags
<section class="login" ng-controller="loginController as vm">
<script src="/static/script/angular-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/script/libs/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="/static/script/libs/angular/dir-pagination.js"></script>
<script src="/static/script/libs/jquery/jquery.raty-fa.js"></script>
<script src="/static/script/angular/gsa.js"></script>

Thank you again